# execute a Thor task located in a bundled gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, command-line-interface, thor

I have a gem, **my_gem**, that has **thor** as a runtime dependency.  I have a subclass of Thor located in the gem at:

`lib/tasks/task.thor`

from the gem's source directory I can run:

```
bundle
thor task:my_task
```

and my_task will be executed.

However, if I include **my_gem** in the Gemfile for another project, when I run:

```
bundle
thor task:my_task
```

I get:

> No thor tasks available

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had a thought that I might need to `bundle exec thor task:my_task`, that still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a full example so that others may try to reproduce the problem? That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: thor tasks from other gems don't get automagically included in your gem. not sure if and how you can tell thor to load these task files from the gem, but since the gem's `lib` folder is in the loadpath, you should be able to load it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that, if I understand this correctly, that your lib/tasks/task.thor is actually a part of the gem itself, and that you expect thor to find your thor file buried in your gem.

If this is the case, this will not work as thor will not look in your gem's directories automatically.

You may want to consider not using thor files at all and simply writing a command that would use thor to process your command-line parameters, like Rails does, for example.

If you really need to run thor in this way, then your gem must do 'the magic' of putting your thor files in the path thor searches.